# Angularjs, Jasmine testing helpers free library (or resource)

Tags: angularjs, tdd, jasmine

Im new to Testing(TDD) (jasmine) and I just want to leverage and expand my knowledge with using libraries that experienced people there wants to share and suggest, anyone there with a helpful set of custom matchers in angular-mocks(jasmine based not pure jasmine) for angularjs? thanks

Comment: Not sure why you would need custom matchers for angular anything you're looking for in particular?

Comment: I wanted to get some more idea to improve my code, like how vojta used a helper .toHaveClass in his talk [here](https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing), and I'm trying not to reinvent..

Answer (score 1):

I am new also in unitesting (jasmine) but this is a simple demo that can help you to sort things out:

- Basic Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zaQUZfYXIniwIqsa3ibJ?p=preview)</kbd>
- Demo with directive <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hsAeXycsfIqSiRoXpzDO?p=preview)</kbd>

Hope it will help